# HTML5 Video: Detect dragging of timeline

Tags: html, video, scroll, drag

I was wondering if there is a full-proof way of knowing when the user is dragging the timeline of an HTML5 video. Thus far I've been binding to timeUpdate, but it's unclear whether the currentTime is increasing due to a drag or simply the video playing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know that [MediaElement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/) which is a html5 video element implementation supports an event called 'seeked' which gives you what you want.

You could use that or look into the code to see what kind of logic they're using for detecting seeking.

Another way is that you can implement your own custom seek bar and if that's the case, you can just handle when the user drags the timeline scrubber to throw up a seeked event. The W3C has a [document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html#seeking) on how to implement the seeking.

Comment: Thanks, hacking the seeked/seeking event was exactly what I needed. 
Seeked is fired every time the video completes its seeking, and seeking is fired when the browser needs to look up a new frame in the video (but not fired when the video is playing normally).

Hence Seeked is continuously fired as the user drags the timeline (also on a discrete jump, but we can separate that case programmatically). If you internally setup a counter for the number of times Seeked has fired, then when that counter stops incrementing the user has stopped dragging.

Answer (score 1):

To detect when the user is dragging the timeline of an HTML5 video, you can use a combination of the `timeupdate`, `seeking`, and `seeked` events. Here's an example

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
var isDragging = false;
video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
    if (isDragging) {
        console.log('Dragging timeline');
    }
});
video.addEventListener('seeking', function() {
    isDragging = true;
});
video.addEventListener('seeked', function() {
    isDragging = false;
});
```