# html5 video seek performance

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, html5-video, seek

I'm writing a simple app to seek an html5 video in both directions by dragging mouse. I also need to overlay stuff on top of the video so I'm using html5 canvas. The video element stays hidden, I play the video and update the canvas image every 20 ms. This much has no performance issues.

However I want to seek the video when I drag the mouse. It turns out that I would need to seek the video every 20 ms which leads to a choppy performance. Another hack I tried was to fast forward the underlying video when I drag. This has almost perfect performance and is sufficient for my use case except I can't rewind and fast-forward the video.

My research says the only way right now to rewind an html5 video is to set the currentTime backwards frame by frame, but again I can't afford to do this every 20ms or the video gets choppy.

Is there any way around these limitations? It would be enough if I can just play the video backwards in normal speed.

Comment: I would suggest not displaying the overlays when seeking the video

Comment: @jasonscript unfortunately that's a business requirement.

Comment: When the mouse is pressed and the user is moving the mouse you should update the video far less often (every 200 ms?), and not play the video. This might be enough.

Comment: @GameAlchemist updating view every 200ms means 5 fps. That will look choppy as hell too.

Comment: The idea is that a user is either seeking OR playing. While you don't move the move, nothing changes (0 fps), and that's in fact right perfect.

Comment: You're supposed to be able to play backwards by setting playbackRate to a negative number, but I suspect that will also have pretty choppy performance. If so, you could probably pre-generate a backwards version of the video, and swap it in when the user drags backwards.

Comment: Also, it sounds like you are probably using setInterval to schedule the canvas updates. You're probably better off using requestAnimationFrame. That will try to match the update frequency with the monitor refresh, and won't keep updating when the tab is hidden.

Comment: @aldel thanks for suggesting requestAnimationFrame, that is almost always a better choice. Setting playbackRate to a negative value should be the proper solution, except that it works nowhere. Using a  pre-generated video is actually the only acceptable solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 Video: Detect dragging of timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946428/html5-video-detect-dragging-of-timeline)

Comment: instead of 20ms have you tried requestanimationframe()? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame