# How Can I track a video timeline drag event through javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-video

HI everyone I am writing an application where I am capturing some data.
I am giving them a video to watch and I need to track where the user rewatched the video
So how can I track the video timeline drag
for example if a video is playing on 1:30 minutes and user go back to 0:50 seconds. I just need to track if user go behind not for the forward. I need to track if user drag currentTime to backward
how can I track it

I tried with seeked addeventlistner but trouble is if I am setting the currentTimestamp in another variable and as soon as I use Seeked it giving me sameTimestamp and update my another variable also

```
lectureVideo.addEventListener('seeked', ()=> {
        var seekedTime = lectureVideo.currentTime;
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log("seeked time");
        if(seekedTime < videoTimeStamp) {
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
            console.log("User rewatch section from" + seekedTime + ',, ');
        }
    });
```

this is simple block of code. videoTimeStamp is my variable where I am trying to set the time again.but its not working.

I tried this
[HTML5 Video: Detect dragging of timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946428/html5-video-detect-dragging-of-timeline)

but now working for me